# how to pass the selected row item in angular ui-grid to fetch data for another ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-grid

I have 2 ui-grids displaying data using 2 different controllers, each controller calling a different service. (service uses ngresource and not http.)
My need is : when one row is selected in 1st grid(vendors), the 2nd grid(contracts) should get data only where the value matches the id that was fetched in the first grid.
So basically when the 1st grid vendors $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged event is triggered the contracts.query should get triggered with the VEID value of the row selected. 
I am new to angular, so not able to figure out exactly where to pass the values and where to add in function to achieve this. I saw the article on $emit and $on, but not clear on it. Also my service uses $ngresource and QUERY method , while most examples are using $http or POST method. Please help!

```js
//app.js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('VendorApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection','ang_venservice','ang_contservice','ui.grid.pinning']);

})();


//vendor controller
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('VendorApp')
        .controller('ang_vencontroller', ang_vencontroller);
    ang_vencontroller.$inject = ['$scope', 'vendors','contracts','$timeout', 'uiGridConstants'];


    function ang_vencontroller($scope, $rootscope,vendors, $timeout, uiGridConstants)
    {
        $scope.vendorsvalues = vendors.query()

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableSelectAll: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enablePagination: true,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            paginationCurrentPage: 1,
            paginationPageSize: 100,
            maxVisibleColumnCount: 200,
            columnDefs: [
              { name: 'VENDORID', field: 'MVE_VEID' },
              { name: 'NAME', field: 'VE_NAME' },
              { name: 'ADDR1', field: 'VE_ADDR1' }
            ],
            data: $scope.vendorsvalues

        };

        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                    $scope.value = row.entity.MVE_VEID;
                    $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
                    //$scope.contractvalues =function(){$rootScope.$emit( contracts.query({ id: $scope.value }))};

                });
              
  
              //contract controller            
              
              (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('VendorApp')
        .controller('ang_contcontroller', ang_contcontroller);

    ang_contcontroller.$inject = ['$scope', 'contracts'];

    function ang_contcontroller($scope, $rootscope,contracts) {
        $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
        $scope.gridoptions2 = {
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableSelectAll: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enablePagination: true,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            paginationCurrentPage: 1,
            paginationPageSize: 100,
            maxVisibleColumnCount: 200,
            columnDefs: [
              { name: 'CONTRACTID', field: 'MCO_COID' },
              { name: 'NAME', field: 'CO_DESC' },
              { name: 'VENDORID', field: 'MCO_VEID' }
            ],
            data: $scope.contractvalues
        };

    }
})();


              //contract service
              
              (function () {
    'use strict';

    var ang_contservice = angular.module('ang_contservice', ['ngResource']);
    ang_contservice.factory('contracts', ['$resource', function ($resource)
    {
        return $resource('/api/ContractsAPI/:id', { id: 0 }, { query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true } });
    }])
})();
```

```html
<body ng-cloak>
    <h4>VENDORS</h4>
    <div ng-controller="ang_vencontroller" >
        <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
        <strong>SelectedRowCount:</strong> <span ng-bind="mySelectedRows.length"></span> 
        <br />
        <strong>SelectedVendor:</strong> <span ng-bind="value"></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4>CONTRACTS</h4>
    <div ng-controller="ang_contcontroller">
        <div id="grid2" ui-grid="gridoptions2" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.
I had to have both the grids in the same controller and that fixed the issue.

This is because the $scope.GridApi is not available between controllers.
U may be able to achieve grids to interact in different controllers using Controller AS , but for now, this serves my purpose.
Below is the working controller code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('VendorApp')
    .controller('ang_vencontroller', ang_vencontroller);
ang_vencontroller.$inject = ['$scope','$rootScope', 'vendors','contracts','$timeout', 'uiGridConstants'];


function ang_vencontroller($scope, $rootScope, vendors, contracts, $timeout, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.vendorsvalues = vendors.query();

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enablePagination: true,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        paginationCurrentPage: 1,
        paginationPageSize: 100,
        maxVisibleColumnCount: 200,
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'VENDORID', field: 'MVE_VEID' },
          { name: 'NAME', field: 'VE_NAME' },
          { name: 'ADDR1', field: 'VE_ADDR1' }
        ],
        data: $scope.vendorsvalues

    };

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            console.info("grid api 1 registered", $scope.gridApi);

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
                $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
                $scope.value = $scope.mySelectedRows[0].MVE_VEID;

                $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                $scope.value = row.entity.MVE_VEID;
                $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
                console.log("scope.contractvalues:", $scope.contractvalues);
                $scope.gridoptions2.data = $scope.contractvalues;
                $scope.gridApi2.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
    $scope.gridoptions2 = {
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enablePagination: true,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        paginationCurrentPage: 1,
        paginationPageSize: 100,
        maxVisibleColumnCount: 200,
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'CONTRACTID', field: 'MCO_COID' },
          { name: 'NAME', field: 'CO_DESC' },
          { name: 'VENDORID', field: 'MCO_VEID' }
        ],
        data: $scope.contractvalues,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi2 = gridApi;
        }

    };
    $scope.gridoptions2.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi2 = gridApi;
        console.info("***grid api 2 registered***", $scope.gridApi2);

    };

}
})();
```